# Is the quantifier a modifier or is it modified, in semantic respect?

Tags: determiners

> "You've met Malfoy before?" 
>     Harry explained about their
>   meeting in Diagon Alley. 
>     "I've heard of his family," said Ron
>   darkly. "They were **some of** the first to come back to our side
>   after You-Know-Who disappeared. Said they'd been bewitched. My dad
>   doesn't believe it. He says Malfoy's father didn't need an excuse to
>   go over to the Dark Side."
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's
>   Stone)

When you say ‘some of’ is the qualifier, does it mean ‘some of’ modifies ‘the first’? Or unlike pre-modifiers, ‘some’ is modified by ‘the first’?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you explain what possible difference in ***meaning*** (i.e. - "in semantic respect") you might understand, dependent on whether you're told that *some of* modifies *the first*, or that *the first* modifies *some*?

Comment: _Some of_ is a **quantifier**, not a qualifier. Quantifiers come before adjectives, and interact oddly with determiners, since they occur together at the beginnings of noun phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Some of* modifies *the first*.  Here, *the first* refers to a bunch of people, and Malfoy's family constituted *some of* that first bunch of people.